# In kivy python how to get data from a url request

Tags: python, request, kivy

I am requesting JSON from a url in kivy. In the main App:

```
data = UrlRequest('http://myhost.ninja/request', gotArticles, onFailure)
```

and the callback:

```
def gotArticles(req, results):
  for key in results:
    return key
```

when I then `print(data)` I get `<UrlRequest(Thread-1, started daemon 123145307557888)>` printed. I can print the data from inside the callback, but how do I return the data to the rest of the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's pretty obvious that you are not attempting to print a function's return(like `print(int('1'))`), but rather object i.e. the whole `UrlRequest` class that you assigned to `data` variable. Same as `print(TextInput())`

Try to print a variable from that object:

```
print(data.result)
```

which is basically [`UrlRequest.result`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html#kivy.network.urlrequest.UrlRequest.result).

**Example:**(`http` is intended only to show that result is present, the real page has `https`)

```
req = UrlRequest('http://kivy.org')
while not req.is_finished:
    sleep(1)                         # seems to be unnecessary in this case
    Clock.tick()

print('result =', req.result)
print('error =', req.error)
```

`wait()` does visually the same thing

```
req = UrlRequest('http://kivy.org')
req.wait()
print('result =', req.result)
print('error =', req.error)
```

Comment: I see that I'm printing the object, but I don't know what variables are available on the `<class 'kivy.network.urlrequest.UrlRequest'>`, `.results` is not

Comment: All that are listed, but you need to look at the [example](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/network/urlrequest.html) at the end of the file. It says you need to wait(check if `data.is_finished` is `True`) and then it'll return some value. All of the functions used as kwargs are executed after the request is finished.

Comment: I called the `.wait()` method on the `UrlRequst`. The affect of which is to the print `none` at my print statement. I believe the link is the source code for the UrIRequest method, not an example.

Comment: @icicleking I updated my answer to be more example-friendly. ^^